# Reload .Renviron or .Rprofile from an active R session (without restarting R)?

Tags: r

When R starts (with default options), it loads the `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` files in the working directory or user's home directory. In my case these files may be changed during the course of the R session (e.g. as [packrat](http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/walkthrough.html) does). I was wondering if there is a way to ask R to simply refresh its `.Renviron` having to quit and restart R?

For instance, in the case of `.Rprofile`, it is sufficient to simply `source(".Rprofile")` to reload the `.Rprofile` from the working directory. Can something similar be managed for `.Renviron`?

Comment: `readRenviron` is your friend. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRenviron.html

Comment: @infominer Just what I needed! I was getting stuck on `Sys.getenv`. If you post that as the answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, just did that! Great lab notebook BTW. Some of your latest entries have exactly what I have been pre-occupied with these past few months!

Comment: @infominer Thanks, still figuring out what's best. You might be interested in http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ (w/ pandoc integration coming to RStudio) if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `readRenviron` Reference: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRenviron.html

Yes I remember getting stuck on Sys.getenv a while ago. and thanks to your question, it reminded me about packrat. Going to use it to distribute some code for a manuscript.

Comment: Would be nice to have a full working example of the actual code that one has to use instead of a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
readRenviron("~/.Renviron")
```

#### Full example

Create a file called `.Renviron` in the directory `~/` (i.e. your home directory). Note: `.Renviron` must have exactly that filename (the `.` means it's a hidden file).

Inside `.Renviron`, place this and save the file:

```
NEWVAR=123
```

Now in your R session, read in the .Renviron file and to show all the environment variables:

```
# Read in .Renviron file you just created
readRenviron("~/.Renviron")

# View environment variables inside your R session
Sys.getenv()
# NEWVAR         123
```

To access a specific variable:

```
Sys.getenv("NEWVAR")
# [1] 123
```